# Unable to start minikube on mac Os Big Sur Apple M1 Chip

Tags: minikube, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am running docker desktop 20.10.8 on my imac. I tried to install minikube and getting the following error when I start minikube.   Do I need to do anything for this to work on  the new macos chip M1?

Here is the error

❌  Exiting due to K8S_APISERVER_MISSING: wait 6m0s for node: wait for apiserver proc: apiserver process never appeared
  Suggestion: Check that the provided apiserver flags are valid, and that SELinux is disabled

Comment: I also cannot get minikube to start on macbook pro m1. I am using Docker Desktop 4.2.0 (70708) , minikube v1.24.0 on Darwin 12.0.1 (arm64) , kubernetes-version=v1.22.3 , macos monterey 12.01

❌ Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION_CONTAINER_EXITED: Docker container exited prematurely after it was created, consider investigating Docker's performance/health.

I have unsuccessfully tried the suggestion 'Running "minikube delete" may fix it'

Comment: Hey @stephennewman Did you manage to solve the GUEST_PROVISION_CONTAINER_EXITED error?? I solved using a different driver instead of the default one. I've already tried Qemu or Podman and they solve the issue, but I actually need the default one which I'm pretty sure is Docker